# Passing object to directive does not allow global variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im passing to my directive a variable `col` defined `col: '='` in the directive.
The object contains some arrays, and inside those arrays there is a function.
The function refers to a variable from my controller, and it looks like this:

```
function (params) {
    return $scope.function(params);
}
```

This`col` variable is being passed to a sub directive that the big directive contains, and the sub-directive executes it.

It throws an error, from a file called *VM{random number here}* where it says that `$scope` is undefined.

How can I make it run from my controller, and not from a virtual JS file?

Answer (score 1):

if you need to pass functionality then you must create service/factory for the job.To use in directive or component i think.

Dont forget services are singleton and factory implements standart factory pattern.

If global means window variables or function dont need to injection just this.windows. .... does the job.

regards.

Comment: Ill give a bit more context. The directive is a table directive, to show data. the function I am passing is a row style function, to style rows. The global variable is additional styling rules from my controller, which are different for every use of the directive. If I use a service for that, my code wont be organized because Ill need to create in it a styling function for each table. (that means I detach a function from my module, to a more global component, which in the future can create a bit of a mess for upgrades - as far as I see it)

Answer (score 0):

call your directive in your html template which you declared for your controller
and simply pass data from your directive to the function used in your controller
so that you can access your directive data on same rendering template of your controller

**Directive**

```
.directive('myDir', function () {
   return {
     'restrict': 'AE',
     'templateUrl': '/directive_page.html',
         'scope': {
           'col': '=',
           'onSelect': '='
         }
   }
   'link': function () {
       // use onselect method here to use values
   }
}
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('myController', function () {
    $scope.setValueFromDirective = function (value) {
       // write your logic to fetch data
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-my-dir="" col="//pass value you want in directive" data-on-select='setValueFromDirective(value)'>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you